# ImageVault fails to find Anonymous user

Tags: episerver

We are using Episerver and ImageVault and it has worked fine for a long time. Until recently when showing albums to public users stopped working for no apparent reason. 
No code changes in our project or change to the surrounding server environment.
An exception is thrown when the IVFileList control databinds. The exception that is thrown is "the trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed".

I have debugged the code and come to the conclusion that the reason for the exception is actually because episerver tries to find a user called "Anonymous" with the WindowsMemberShipProvider. I have included a simplified stack trace below (excluded several calls for readability). I starts of with the DataBind call which leads to a call to episervers multiplexprovider to find the user "Anonymous" this in turn leads to a call to the method TranslateToSids that throws the exception.

`System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(...)`

`EPiServer.Security.MultiplexingMembershipProvider.FindMembershipUser("Anonymous")`

`ImageStoreNET.Developer.WebControls.IVFileListData.DataBind()`

I found a workaround for this problem by creating an local account in the webserver and named it "Anonymous". And now it all works again! The TranslateToSids method no longer throws the exception and the album pictures are visible.

Does anyone have a theory why this account suddenly is needed? We never had one before as we can recall. Although the workaround works, it feels like a ugly solution to create a local account. It should be a more correct way of solving this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Versioning information on both EPiServer and ImageVault would be useful

Comment: Happens in both Epi v 6 R1 and R2, with ImageVault 3.5.7 (me and jom76 work together)